# Spdycheck is OK but Chrome 42 has Not Spdy Enabled

Tags: nginx, google-chrome, spdy

I am trying to implement spdy protocol with Nginx 1.8.0. I've built it with spdy module.

When I check my website through spdycheck.org it is everything green and says spdy 3.1 is supported, but chrome extension in Chrome 42 doesn't show green arrow and says it is not enabled. I've also checked chrome://net-internals/#spdy and my website is not listed there.

I've got my SHA2 certificate at StartSSL.

SSL Labs gives me grade A+ with almost perfect score.

**Nginx config:**

```
server {
    listen         xx.xx.xx.xx:80;
    server_name    domain.com www.domain.com;
    return         301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen         xx.xx.xx.xx:443 ssl spdy;
    server_name    domain.com www.domain.com;

    if ($host = 'domain.com' ) {
        return 301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
    }

    if ($host = 'it.domain.com' ) {
        return 301 http://it.domain.com$request_uri;
    }

    ssl on;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers    on;
    ssl_session_cache            shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout          10m;
    ssl_protocols                TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    # Cloudflare recommended
    ssl_ciphers                  EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    # Mozilla recommended
    #ssl_ciphers                  'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_certificate              /var/nginx/ssl/site.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key          /var/nginx/ssl/site.key;
    ssl_dhparam                  /var/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate      /var/nginx/ssl/startssl_trust_chain.crt;
    ssl_stapling                 on;
    ssl_stapling_verify          on;
    resolver                     8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;

    add_header    Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; preload";
    add_header    X-Frame-Options "DENY";
    add_header    X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    access_log    /home/virtual/domain.com/logs/access.log main;
    error_log     /home/virtual/domain.com/logs/error.log notice;
    root          /home/virtual/domain.com/subs/www;
    index         index.php index.html;

    rewrite ^/it\.html http://it.domain.com permanent;

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|js|css|ico|swf)$ {
        expires    30d;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
         deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files                $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_pass             phpfarm;
        fastcgi_index            index.php;
        fastcgi_param            SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/virtual/domain.com/subs/www/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffer_size      32k;
        fastcgi_buffers          32 32k;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include                  /var/nginx/conf/fastcgi.conf;

        if ($request_uri ~* "^/index.php\??$") {
            rewrite ^/.*$ http://$host? permanent;
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone any idea why it doesn't want to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you connecting to `it.domain.com` with Chrome? Because I don't see a config for that domain listed anywhere. Also, using the `ssl on` directive isn't recommended if you have ssl in the `listen` directive (See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution but I don't know if it was Chrome cache or Avast.

After emptying whole browser cache, deleted all the browser data and disabled Avast for 10 minutes it started to show me green arrow.

Now it is showing me even though Avast is enabled.

**EDIT**

Is was Avast fault. Web Shield HTTPS scanning has some issues with this.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 for ciphers.
This worked for me.  Im using google chrome Version 44.0.2403.125 m